# How long does it take to get your Facebook account back after you scan your ID?

Tags: facebook, facebook-account

How long does it take to get your Facebook account back after you scan your ID? I have been waiting 3 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't provide a fixed timeframe. Only they know how long it will take.  It can be days, weeks, months, or you could also never get your account back.

It totally depends on Facebook. They also make decisions based on what kind of violation you have done and how many times you have violated rules.

Keep contacting them.

Comment: Thank you ..My account got hacked so I don't have any violation on my account...

Comment: Case different but still it is totally depend on Facebook.

Answer (score -2):

Typically you would need an email. Rather than a phone. Follow the instructions of the site by clicking “forgot password”. As for the sim, request a friend to lend his phone, contact your carrier and explain the situation to the consultant. Request a number transfer from the lost sim to the new one. And ENSURE NOT TO LOSE IT!